# Different gpu without sli.how will it work in terms of memory

Tags: gpu

I want to use gpu without sli to render.so how will this work? Example if i have a 8 gb and 11 gb card....will my system bottle neck and only use 8gb when rendering or will total of 19 gb of memory be available.

Comment: Welcome to BSE @LearningVFX, I believe you mistakenly posted this question here, this is not a question about Blender, I'll vote to close this question as off topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graphics hardware and not about Blender.

Comment: I mean i want to do this for blender...how will blender handle this?

Answer (score 2):

The cards are completely separate, they do not share memory. Whatever the lowest amount  of vram (in your case 8gb) will be the limit in blender.

The reason being that the whole scene is loaded onto each card. They are very likely rendering at different speeds, meaning your stronger card will be rendering more tiles then the weaker card.
(Think of it as if each graphics card is a computer in a render farm.)

Comment: So its does bottleneck  the performance ...cheers